# Why is the Xtend standalone command line compiler so slow compared to the Eclipse live version?

Tags: xtext, xtend

I have built a standalone command-line compiler for my DSL; it produces the expected files, but much more slowly (10 seconds) than the code generation performed by the Eclipse editor built for the same DSL (about half a second).
How can I improve the execution time of the code generation process?

Comment: The information you provide are insufficient. How should someone else than you know why your code is slow? I think you have to investigate why your code is not as fast as the one from eclipse. If you then have more specific questions someone might be able to answer.

Comment: what do you use xbase? mean by standalone command line? for me this sounds like https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-extras/issues/261 and https://github.com/xtext/xtext-gradle-plugin/issues/89. if you dont use xbase. do you make use of ResourceDescriptionsData for faster index looksups

Comment: did you do profiling? what exactly is slow. the generation or parsing and linking?

Comment: or the creation of the injector?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich No, I don't use Xbase; my DSL is simple enough to be written with Xtend. By 'standalone command line compiler', I mean the Jar file you can create by adding generateXtendMain=true to the generator specification of the MWE2 file and then exporting a runnable Jar file in Eclipse than you can execute with `java -jar dsl-compiler.jar <path-to-myfile.dsl>`

Comment: you really should do some profiling what is actualy parsing and resolving/validation and what is generation and what is creation of the injector. another question: do you have `@Check(CheckType.EXPENSIVE)` checks?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich No, I don't use Xbase; my DSL is simple enough to be written with Xtend. By 'standalone command line compiler', I mean the Jar file you can create by adding generateXtendMain=true to the generator specification of the MWE2 file and then exporting a runnable Jar file in Eclipse than you can execute with `java -jar dsl-compiler.jar <path-to-myfile.dsl>` No I don't use ResourceDescriptionsData and I even did not know about it; I am a basic user of these smart technologies and this is why I did not do any profiling.

Comment: i recommend you to profile your application so that you know "where" the time is spent. then we can discuss what can be optimized

Comment: Profiling the app revealed time spent in processing Jar content. The performance issue came from the Jar file which was built with the "Package required libraries into generated JAR" option. Using the "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" solved the performance issue". Thanks for the profiling suggestion; I did not believe it could be of any help in that situation...